# Checking result of EXPECT_* macros in GTest or run code when ASSERT_* failed

Tags: c++, testing, googletest

I have written C++ tests with GTest which basically work like this

```
MyData data1 = runTest(inputData);
MyData data2 = loadRegressionData();

compareMyData(data1,data2);
```

with

```
void compareMyData(MyData const& data1, MyData const& data2)
{
  ASSERT_EQ(data1.count, data2.count);
  //pseudo:
  foreach element in data1/data2:
    EXPECT_EQ(data1.items[i], data2.items[i]);
}
```

Now I would like to save the `data1` contents to a file IFF the test fails and I don't see 
an elegant solution yet.

---

First approach: **Make `compareMyData` return the comparison result.** This can't work with the `ASSERT_EQ` which is fatal. Writing `if (!EXPECT_EQ(...))` doesn't compile so the only way I found is

```
bool compareMyData(MyData const& data1, MyData const& data2)
{
  EXPECT_EQ(data1.count, data2.count);
  if (data1.count != data2.count)
    return false;
  //pseudo:
  foreach element in data1/data2:
  {
    EXPECT_EQ(data1.items[i], data2.items[i]);  
    if (data1.items[i]!= data2.items[i])
      return false;
  }
}
```

Not very elegant :-(

---

Second idea: **Run code when the test failed**

I know I can implement `::testing::EmptyTestEventListener` and get notified if a test fails, but that doesn't give me the data I want to write to file and it is "far away" from the place I'd like it to have. So my question here is: Is there a way to run code at the end of a test if it failed (e.g. catching an exception?).

---

To ask more general: how would you solve this?

Comment: Why do you want the data in a file?

Comment: @doctorlove: the tested code performs numeric calculations on large input data sets. By writing the results to disk I can load and analyze them properly with visualization tools to see what went wrong and when. (These are regression tests that also test some integration of the whole system. We have Unit tests as well where evaluation of the test data is simpler.) If everything's fine, I don't want to write the data to file because the amount of data is big.

Comment: Google Test has a number of ways to deal with this. Check out their wiki section on detecting failures inside the test and in subroutines in particular the documentation on [Propagating Fatal Failures](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#propagating-fatal-failures).

Comment: thanks for the hint. I didn't know that ASSERT_* simply uses `return;`. However, I don't see a way how to use this concretely because my method returns bool, so using an ASSERT_* even results in a compiler error (cannot convert void to bool). Do you have an idea what to do?

Comment: The text just below that section discusses how you can use HasFailure() and HasFatalFailure() to find out the outcome of the test so far.

Comment: Links to GTest/GMock have changed. Here is the link to the advance guide:

https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md

Comment: Thank, updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

[On the advanced guide](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Propagating_Fatal_Failures) that VladLosev linked, it says,

```
Similarly, HasNonfatalFailure() returns true if the current test has at least one non-fatal failure, and HasFailure() returns true if the current test has at least one failure of either kind.
```

So calling `HasNonfatalFailure` might be what you want.
(I'm pretty late, but had the same question.)

Comment: Links to GTest/GMock have changed. Here is the link to the advance guide:

https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md

Answer (score 0):

The way around:

```
bool HasError = false;
FAIL() << (HasError = true);
if (HasError){
 // do something
}
```

Instead of FAIL() could be ASSERT_.. EXPECT_... and so on. (in output you'll see "true" it's a fee for shortcut).